# My APP won't GC until no free memory or force GC

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

My APP do some networking if you press a button.

I found the memory allocated is always increasing, the GC never happen until there is no free memory or I use force GC button in Android Studio Monitor, and force GC will always make the allocated memory to the initial state, a fixed value when run the APP the first time without any operation.

Is that natural? GC until the OS has no choice?

And Can that prove I have no memory leak? Since GC will send back all memory allocated.

Comment: Locate and limit memory leaks: https://medium.com/freenet-engineering/memory-leaks-in-android-identify-treat-and-avoid-d0b1233acc8#.a8ssacbta

Answer (score 0):

I've worked in an image effects application and it usually takes up the whole memory before GC works and empty some of it, then it goes with the same behavior again